# PHP simple HTML Dom select inner text only not child inne rtext

Tags: php, html, dom

I'm using PHP simple HTML DOM class to parse html.
I want to select div with `id="content"` inner text, but when I call `$selecrot->plaintext`, it also return sub div text

**Sample HTML**

```
<div id="content">
Hello World.
<div id="sub-content1">
Text I don't want to select.
</div>
<div id="sub-content2">
Text I don't want to select
</div>
</div>
```

**Sample code**

```
//suppose $html contains above html
$selector = $html->find("div#content", 0); 
echo $selector->innertext; 
//it outputs "Hello World. Text I don't want to select. Text I don't want to select"
//but
```

I want only "Hello World"

Comment: This question is not related to jquery. Not a duplicate question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
include_once('simple_html_dom.php');
$html = new simple_html_dom();

$text = '<div id="content">
Hello World.
<div id="sub-content1">
Text I don\'t want to select.
</div>
<div id="sub-content2">
Text I don\'t want to select
</div>
</div>';

$html->load($text);
$selector =$html->find("div#content",0)->find("*");
foreach($selector  as $node){
$node->outertext = '';
}
$html->load($html->save()); 
$selector =$html->find("div#content",0);
echo $selector->innertext;
```

Comment: provide some explaination

Comment: Step 1: Find all nodes of selector, Step 2: NULL all nodes, Step 3: Reload simple HTML DOM, after step 3 selector contents is '<div id="content">Hello World.</div>'